# node_acl with ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, node-acl

I am trying to use node_acl plugin, as stated in the README

```
...
const conn = mongoose.connection;

var acl = require('acl');

// Using the mongodb backend
acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(dbInstance, prefix));
```

so I wrote

```
[30] let acl = require('acl');
[31]
[32] acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.db, 'acl'));

[30] let acl = require('acl');
[31]
[32] conn.on('connected', (error) => {
[33]   if (error) throw error;
[34]   acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(conn.db, 'acl_'));
[35] });
```

but ESLint is raising 2 errors

```
  ✖  34:13  A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter  new-cap
  ✖  34:25  A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter  new-cap
```

How should I use it with ES8 ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: Styling errors, not actual errors. `let Acl = require('acl');` should keep eslint happy. Not sure about `acl.mongodbBackend`. Might need to do `const { mongodbBackend: MongoDbBackend } = Acl;`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback . it works 
I tried to I use      "capIsNew": [0],   in my .eslintrc do disable the warning for mongodbBackend.. but wo any success

Comment: sorry .. the rule should be. "new-cap": [0, "newIsCap"],